# image not showing when transferred using InputStream and OutputStream in java

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

This is my test program. I need it to apply somewhere.This may be small, sorry for that. But I'm a starter still. So kindly help me.

```
try{
        File file1 = new File("c:\\Users\\prasad\\Desktop\\bugatti.jpg");
        File file2 = new File("c:\\Users\\prasad\\Desktop\\hello.jpg");
        file2.createNewFile();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
        String data = null;
        StringBuilder imageBuild = new StringBuilder();
        while((data = reader.readLine())!=null){
            imageBuild.append(data);
        }
        reader.close();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file2)));
        writer.write(imageBuild.toString());
        writer.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is file1
[image]

and This is file2
[image]

Comment: Ummm why are you doing `data = reader.readLine()`? with a `jpg` file..? I'm pretty sure you need to use a `byte[]` for this

Comment: you need to use BufferedImage and ImageIO for your requirements here. Please check this link: https://www.dyclassroom.com/image-processing-project/how-to-read-and-write-image-file-in-java

Comment: The first line of the Javadocs states `Reads text from a character-input stream, `

Comment: So what to use instead? I thought image will be transformed in the form of bytes. So I used InputStream to read bytes into a BufferedReader and printed it. @ScaryWombat

Comment: So what to use instead? I thought image will be transformed in the form of bytes. So I used InputStream to read bytes into a BufferedReader and printed it. @a3.14_Infinity

Comment: maybe a `ByteArrayInputStream`

Comment: Please check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/ . Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either of these two:

```
private static void copyFile(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
}
```

or maybe this if you want to use streams:

```
private static void copyFile(File source, File dest)
throws IOException {
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
try {
    input = new FileInputStream(source);
    output = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
        output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} finally {
    input.close();
    output.close();
}
}
```

Comment: thanks bro. Its working. but what i dont understand is why you took byte array size 1024?

Comment: @Krishna   It can be any size really but usually that is typically what people do. 1MB at a time. You can go bigger but no reason to

Comment: yeah. thanks. Now I need to send this stream of bytes in network to another pc. how can I send? Do I need to convert it into a string and send it in parameters using http? Actually that is the reason why I took BufferedReader.

Comment: @Krishna  So you want to send the image to another computer? You need to use the same streams but Create `Sockets` and `ServerSockets` and on the sockets call `getOutputStream / `getInputStream`

Comment: @Krishna: I now understand why you are using streams here and not BufferedImage or ImageIO

Comment: @3Kings 1024 bytes is 1k at a time, not 1Mb, and it's too small. Should be at least 4-8k.

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity Yup. Thanks man. Its really nice to get response like this. Got to know many things from this only question. And yes. I tried to use streams just because I can send it on network. :-)

Comment: So should I send the bytes in loop calling the host multiple times? Is that not possible with Buffer So that I can send all the data at once?

Comment: We can use the same input taking it into BufferedInputStream bro. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Images do not contain lines or even characters. You therefore should not be using `readLine()` or even `Readers` or `Writers.` You should rewrite the copy loop using input and output streams directly.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. now actually I want to send the image on a network.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. now actually I want to send the image on a network. So should I send the bytes in loop calling the host multiple times? Is that not possible with Buffer?

Comment: @Krishna I don't understand what you're asking. Please define 'calling the host multiple times', and clarify how it differs from what happens in a standard copy loop.